# setting property "print directly to printer"

Tags: powershell, printing, windows-server-2012

I have made a script for adding a printer and port to a print server. The server handles the queue's and uses add a queue to start printing. However since the server is quite far from many of the printers i would like to activate the option "Print directly to the printer" (Which is found in, Printer ->Properties -> Advanced)

[image]

What is the PowerShell equivalent for this option?

```
$PortName = Read-Host "Name of port : "
$PortIp = Read-Host "IP Adress : "
Add-PrinterPort -Name $PortName -PrinterHostAddress $PortIp
Get-PrinterDriver
Write-Host "---------------------"
$PrintDriver = Read-Host "Print driver :"
if ($PrintDriver.Equals("HP")){ $PrintDriver = "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"}
$PrinterLocation = Read-Host "Location : "
Add-Printer -Name $PortName -DriverName $PrintDriver -Shared -Location $PrinterLocation    -Published -PortName $PortName
```

I have tried `-RenderingMode`  but i couldnt see that that made any difference

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PowerShell and WMI:

```
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name = 'PrinterName'"
$printer.Direct = $true
$printer.Put()
```

Probably should put a try {} catch {} around that as well.

This will also set the `SpoolerEnabled` (deprecated read only property) and the `DoCompleteFirst` property both to `$false`.

http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_printer/